# Executing a function with fixed memory resources

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory

I have a list of models that I am preprocessing:

```
def preprocess(model):
    from somewhere import apply_calc
    try:
        return apply_calc(model)
    except:
        return False 

for model in all_models
    preprocessed_model = preprocess(model)
```

My problem is, some models are so big, that my "preprocess" function uses all of my MEM (32G) and all of my SWP (32G) and even if I have the "try except" part, my entire script gets killed by linux with OOM.

My idea of solving it is to run "preprocess" function as a thread and using only a fixed amount of memory resource. Something like this:

run_thread(function=preprocess, arg=model, memory_limit=40G)

Now either "preprocess" will be able to do the calculations using 40 GB of memory and it will return the preprocessed model, or it will fail and will just return a "False".

Could you please tell me if this looks like an ok approach and how to run a thread with a limit on memory resource? I am using python 2.7

Comment: Looks like and X, Y problem.

Comment: @James: you mean apply_calc shouldnt eat the entire MEM and SWP? The problem is, its a third party software and I do not have that much time to reimplement it.